# why does my document fail with sideways from rotating package?

Tags: tables, rotating

I want to test landscape tables, and started with the sideways environment. However the code does not compile, I get the error:

```
(./content/landscapetable.tex
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.6 \begin{center}
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sideways}
\begin{center}
  \centering 
%  \captionsetup{type=table}
%  \caption{Sehr breite Tabelle.}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textheight}{XXX}
\hline
head & head & head \\
\hline
text which is considereably longer than 
the width of the column & 
text which is considereably longer than 
the width of the column & 
text which is considereably longer than 
the width of the column \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}  
\end{center}
\end{sideways}
\end{document}
```

Remove the sideways environment, and it compiles.

EDIT: when the center env is removed, and centering is left and the caption is introduced again another error with the caption occurs.

```
\begin{sideways}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{type=table}
  \caption{Sehr breite Tabelle.}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textheight}{*{6}{X}}
\hline
head & head & head & head & head & head \\
...
\end{tabularx}  
\end{sideways}
```

The error is then

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
\endgroup
l.5 \caption{Sehr breite Tabelle.}
```

With sidewaystable it works, but that is not what I want.

Comment: For the record another solution is given [Question 96354][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96354/sideways-figures/96491#96491

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why both `\centering` and the `center` environment? Remove the latter and the example compiles fine.

---

(New solution, based on comment.)

If you did not want to rotate the caption, why put the caption in the `sideways` environment? What you could do is to place the table in a normal `table` environment, and then put just the `tabularx` in `sideways`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering 
  \captionsetup{type=table}
  \caption{Sehr breite Tabelle.}
  \begin{sideways}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textheight}{XXX}
    \hline
    head & head & head \\
    \hline
    text which is considereably longer than 
    the width of the column & 
    text which is considereably longer than 
    the width of the column & 
    text which is considereably longer than 
    the width of the column \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{sideways}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I think it would be better to use `sidewaystable`, and have the caption rotated as well. Having to turn the page between reading the caption and reading the table would be awkward and inconvenient.

Comment: I know booktabs, but this was a minimal example. sidewaystable is something different (the caption is rotated too), which I do not want. I updated the question with a new error

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Ah, I see. You should add a line stating what you _do_ want to your question as well, just to make it clear (tabular rotated, caption not rotated).