# Sideways figures

Tags: rotating

I'm using the command `sidewaysfigures` to put my landscape graphics (`pdf` images) the right way. The images are correctly positioned in a new page, but the problem is that if I go on writing after the

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure} 
...
```

command, on the output the rotated images are shifted to the last page available. Of course I don't want this to happen and I've tried to specify `[h]` or `[!h]` commands but it doesn't seem to work!

Does anyone know what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi Francesco, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) I edited your question and marked up the code a bit using the `{}` button and back ticks. I also removed the thanks- it may seem strange, but we say 'thank you' on this site by up voting :) I also removed your name since it is displayed at the bottom right of your question- welcome :)

Comment: This seems to me as if the images were too big to fit into the text area of your document. If you have a look at your log files there should be a badbox warning indicating that the box of your image is too wide/high which would make it go to the end of your document. maybe you could give us some [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that could provide clarification.

Comment: I believe that (1) `sidewaysfigure` is singular (no `s` at the end) and (2) it is always put on a page of its own, hence you might try to use `[p]` or `[!p]` instead of `[h]`; as well in case `[p]` is not specified, LaTeX often pushed floats into the very end.

Comment: Got it, the problem was that I had to put `[p]` instead of `[h]` as @tohecz suggested! Thanks for the hint!
PS: yes, its `sidewaysfigure`, with no `s` at the end.

Comment: @cmhughes thanks for the hints, so how do I vote someone?

Comment: @Francesco you're welcome :) You upvote answers using the 'up arrow' button. I think you need to have a minimum reputation to do so, but as soon as you reach it, go ahead! Note that you can (and should) upvote more than one answer if you find it appropriate- not only on your own questions, but on other questions too. Voting and reputation are the 'currency' for our community :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `sidewaysfigure` always occupies a whole page, the specifier `[h]` makes no sense. Moreover, if you specify `[h]` and LaTeX finds it cannot place the float `h`ere, it pushes it to the end of the chapter/document (of to the next `\clearpage`).

**Solution:** Do not specify anything with `sidewaysfigure` and it will appear on the next page. You can as well specify `[p]` if you want (it shouldn't change anything though).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pdflscape package as shown in the example below, I find that there is a better control of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  

\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\Large
\begin{center}
\input{Table}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}   
\newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum\ldots
\end{document}
```

The Table.tex file is

```
\begin{tabular}[htbp]{l|l|c|l|l}
\hline
Lorem &  Ipsum &Dolor& Sit & Amet \\
\hline
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
&&&&\\
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
&&&&\\
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
&&&&\\
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
&&&&\\
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
&&&&\\
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
&&&&\\
adipisicing&exercitation& consequat& voluptate&deserunt\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{adipisicing exercitation consequat voluptate deserunt}
```

The result is

[image]